# Equivalent of \providecommand that allows :c specifier

Tags: macros, expl3

Is there something equivalent to \providecommand in expl3 but allows `:c` specifier? Given a string as the command name, I need to define the new command in the following way:

1. If the command existed, then do not define it
2. If the command does not exist, then define it, but in such a way that when user tries to define this command again, the definition would be directly overwritten without raising an error.

The reason for this is that I wish to provide some shortcut macros in a package, but I wish to do this "quietly", i.e. do not overwrite existed macros and do not prevent the users from defining their own version. I am aware that there is a `\ProvideDocumentCommand`, but it seems only to accept `:N` argument as the command name.

Comment: `\cs_if_exist:cF { foo } { \cs_new_protected:cpn {foo} {whatever} }`

Comment: No built-in method.  `expl3` has only `\cs_new...` and `\cs_set...`.  "provide" is a document-level abstraction.  You would need to test yourself.  Also, it's not possible to "when user tries to define this command again, the definition would be directly overwritten without raising an error", because TeX has no way to mark a macro as "this can be redefined"

Comment: I would strongly advise not doing this in your package, it will mean that after loading your package and a potentially conflicting one, the meaning of `\shortmacro` may be defined in different ways depending on package loading order with no warning, this will be confusing and hard to debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for this advice, I will add an option for enabling those shortcuts, and disable them by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next latex release (already available as `pdflatex-dev` in texlive) will allow you to use

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExpandArgs{c}\ProvideDocumentCommand{zzz}{m}{abc#1xyz}

\begin{document}

\zzz{123}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm too slow ;-)

Comment: This will of course still cause any later use of `\newcommand\zzz` by a user to error

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes

Comment: The same functionality can be done with auxiliary macro... but is more verbose.

Comment: @user202729 oh sure it is simply `\expandafter\ProvideDocumentCommand\csname zzz\endcsname{m}{abc#1xyz}` in this case where the exp_args spec is a single `c`

Comment: But expandafter is expl3-ugly... (on that, why not just \exp_args:Nc ...)

Comment: @user202729 but there is no expl3 code on view here (which is why we are adding `\ExpandArgs` for contexts where you want to keep it that way.) `\ExpandArgs` _is_ `\exp_args:...`